# Add third key to array of objects summing up values of second key

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, javascript-objects

I know this might be an easy task though I am struggling quite a lot with this one:

I have an Array of objects looking like this:

```
[{date: '01-01-2022' , count: 1},
 {date: '02-01-2022' , count: 2},
 {date: '05-01-2022' , count: 9}]
```

My expected outcome would be:

```
[{date: '01-01-2022' , count: 1 , sum: 1},
 {date: '02-01-2022' , count: 2 , sum: 3},
 {date: '05-01-2022' , count: 9 , sum: 12}]
```

or alternatively:

```
[{date: '01-01-2022' , count: 1},
 {date: '02-01-2022' , count: 3},
 {date: '05-01-2022' , count: 12}]
```

I can sum up the count array using

```
    let new_array = [];  
    myarray.reduce( (prev, curr,i) =>  new_array[i] = prev + curr , 0 )
    return (new_array);
```

but I never manage to let it happen in the original array of objects or adding the thing to the original array of objects.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure putting the running sum inside the data array is the right approach; if anything reorders the array, the subtotals won't make any sense. Though I guess as long as the subtotals are in the order determined by the date field, you're fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to mutate the original array don't create a new one (`let new_array = [];`), simply iterate over the original and add the property you want to each object.

```js
const input = [{ date: '01-01-2022', count: 1 }, { date: '02-01-2022', count: 2 }, { date: '05-01-2022', count: 9 }]

let sum = 0;
for (const o of input) {
  o.sum = (sum += o.count);
}

console.log(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that would work for your case since you want to do it in original array of objects:

```js
let myArray = [{date: '01-01-2022' , count: 1},
 {date: '02-01-2022' , count: 2},
 {date: '05-01-2022' , count: 9}];

myArray.map((entry, index, arr) => {
    entry.sum = index? arr[index-1].sum + entry.count : entry.count;
    delete entry.count; // Provides alternative outcome, remove for expected outcome
    return entry;
});

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: You're using `map()` as a `forEach` here, just use `forEach`

Comment: I thought of using forEach. Where do I have to put it?

Comment: instead of the `map` – `myArray.forEach((entry, index, arr) => {...`

Comment: @Hemant Singh Bisht `map` method for creating a new set of array you don't need to change the exiting array. if that is the case you can use `for loops` `forEach`  just like @pilchard said

Comment: Map does modify the original array too which was the requirement. However, it additionally returns it too. I had learned somewhere that map is faster than forEach so I got into this BAD habit of using map if it can replace forEach. Thank you for the suggestions, though.

Answer (score 1):

**we can achieve by map also**

```js
   

 

const input = [{ date: '01-01-2022', count: 1 },{ date: '02-01-2022', count: 2 },{ date: '05-01-2022', count: 9 }]

const fun = (ar)=>{
  var t = 0
  const get = ar.map((e, i)=> {
    t = t+e.count
    const Data = {date : e.date,count : e.count,sum : t}
    return Data
})
  return get
}
console.log(fun(input))
```